# how to use standalone class with option [multi=tcolorbox]?

Tags: standalone

MWE:

```
! pdflatex
\documentclass[multi=tcolorbox,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]  
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I just want to get a cropped figure in each page with a simple method.(no to use `preview` wrap every `tcolorbox`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome! Here is an alternative way to make each `tcolorbox` as separate page. It does not use the standalone class, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbset{before=\begin{preview},after=\end{preview}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]  
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick is to automatically wrap the `tcolorbox` in a `preview` environment via

```
 \tcbset{before=\begin{preview},after=\end{preview}}
```

This trick may be combined with [John Kormylo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547634/194703) nice answer to get

```
\documentclass[multi=wrapper,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}
\tcbset{before=\begin{wrapper},after=\end{wrapper}}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapper}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]  
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapper}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @John Kormylo @Schrödinger's-cat Many Thanks! I prefer the trick using `article` documentclass. It's clear and simple. But what confused me is why `standalone` class can not directly using the option [multi=tcolorbox]. It push the user to redefine a new nonsense enviorment.

Comment: @user26992 It has to do with the `saveboxes` that are created, and is not specific to `tcolorbox`. If you consider `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}
\savebox\mybox{\tikz{\node{boom};}}
\tikz{\node{boom};}
\end{document}`, you get the same effect, and if you comment out the `\savebox` it runs through. (I am not claiming that this cannot be fixed somehow.)

Comment: In the last piece of code, the manually added `\begin{wrapper}` and `\end{wrapper}` calls should be removed.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly a solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass[multi=wrapper,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapper}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]  
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapper}

\end{document}
```