# Expand the page height to the tcolorbox height

Tags: tcolorbox, geometry, page

Each tcolorbox must be put on each page for presentation. Some page is overflowed when the tcoloxbox's contents are beyonded height. How can the page height expand in this situation.
This is my MWE, the second page's height need to expanded.
Thank you in advance!
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,papersize={15cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\newpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[15]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[3-30]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[15]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of expanding the page, I'd suggest to break the box is as many pages as needed. It's easy to do it with `break` library from `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,papersize={15cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\newpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[15]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, colback=red!30]
    \lipsum[3-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[15]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: `incgraph`**

`incgraph` package is used to compile an image collection but keeping the individual page size. This package can be used to declare several pages with size adapted to their length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{inctext}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!30]
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}
Just a line
\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have knowd this option. But the contents must be in one slide (page)

Comment: Tcolorbox alse can fit text width box height. But it is difficulty to read because this size is small.

Comment: @NamTranLe I don't understand you. You want to put a lot of text inside a large slide, but when you project it, the text will be so small that nobody will read it. Is this what you want?

Comment: If you want to mix different page sizes, you can try with `incgraph` (an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287054/1952). I'm not sure if you need to have independent images previously compiled to include at their real size.

Comment: You can exit presentation this slide, scoll it.

Comment: The geometry can set up new page size and restore with \restoregeometry command. The difficulty is when we need enlarge the page automaticcally.

Comment: @NamTranLe I've added an updated using `incgraph` to define individual pages. A similar solution can be applied to your other question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620162/1952

Comment: @lgnasi. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something as follows. It is mainly taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547635/73317), except that I removed the manually added `\begin{wrapper}` and `\end{wrapper}` calls that are unneeded due to the `\tcbset{before=\begin{wrapper}, after=\end{wrapper}}` piece of code (automatically adding them is its very purpose!).

```
\documentclass[multi=wrapper,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}
\tcbset{before=\begin{wrapper}, after=\end{wrapper}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[15]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[3-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[12]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [multi=tcolorbox] would be simpler.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: A long time ago.  I had totally forgotten.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547633/how-to-use-standalone-class-with-option-multi-tcolorbox/547634?r=SearchResults&s=1|29.5490#547634

Comment: @JohnKormylo Indeed, you were there. :-)

Comment: Thank you. But my sides also have header and footer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It will make errors. You can combine with varwidth package.

Comment: It likes this https://ibb.co/7GNNsr5

Comment: @NamTranLe - All you need to look like the link is \raggedbottom and a big enough page size.